# Getting path to NSData

Tags: ios

I have a method which requires to enter the path of the file I want to upload (fromPath:@""), and I have to do this for a lot of different NSData. The only method I came up with is save the data, upload it, and then delete, in a for loop for every piece of NSData:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *PhotoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEMP - %d", userID]];
[data writeToFile:PhotoPath atomically:YES];
```

and then use the file at PhotoPath. But this is not a great method.

PS:

the data is initially saved but it is archived and fromPath doesn't read it, so I need to unarchive it and add everything to an array:

```
NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:@"FolderInfo" forFolderNumber:1111 forUser:userID];
```

If either way there was a faster way, like:

NSData* data;
...from path: data directly ...

EDIT:

the whole code might be useful:

```
- (void)syncAllFilesForMyUser:(int)userID InFolder:(int)folderNumber{

NSArray* arr = [DKStoreManager getFileNameListForUser:userID andFolderCode:folderNumber];
for (NSString* str in arr) {
    [DropBlocks uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:[DKStoreManager pathForFileWithName:str inFolderNumber:folderNumber forUser:userID] completionBlock:^(NSString* uploadId, unsigned long long offset, NSDate* expiresDate, NSError* error){

        //[DropBlocks loadRevisionsForFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d/%d/%@", userID, folderNumber, str] completionBlock:^(NSArray* revisions, NSError* error){

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Chunk unsuccessful");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Chunk successful, ready for upload");

            [[self restClient] uploadFile:str toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d/%d", userID, folderNumber] withParentRev:nil fromUploadId:uploadId];
        }

    }];  //}];
}}
```

This is the method uploadFile:str toPath: (dropbox)

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach exactly?  You could write a convenience method for that so it's just a 1-liner.  And actually, you only need to do the first two lines once, right?

Comment: yes, but re-saving all the data? Isn't that slow?